# Finding an Entity based on a list of Entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, domain-driven-design

Suppose we have Group -> Member (ManyToMany)

With a given set of Member - what's the most practical way to find if a Group has been created for exactly those members? (No additional or absent members)

This feels wrong, because Group seems to be defined by it's state, but the system requires us to only ever have one Group for a specific combination of members (including order!)

Edit:

I'm looking for a way to accomplish this using JPA - so Set.retainAll doesn't seem to apply.

What I'm saying is, this would be perfect:

```
List<Member> members;

... // members gets assigned

TypedQuery<Group> query = entityManager.createQuery("select g from Group g where g.members = ?", Group.class)

query.setParameter(1, members);

Group group = query.getSingleResult();
```

Of course that isn't how it works. Consider the worst implementation

```
List<Group> groups = entityManager.createQuery("select g from Group g", Group.class).getResultList();

for (Group g: groups) {
    if (g.getMembers().equals(members)) {
        return g;
    }
}
```

Somewhere between those two has to be something I am missing.

Comment: The one hack I've come up with so far is to store a hash and then fully verify the member collection (to guard against hash collisions).

Comment: Are you looking for just a lookup mechanism, or are you also looking to prevent the application from being able to create two groups with the same members in a multi-threaded environment?

Comment: Just the lookup mechanism would be fine - it's a matter of processing a bunch of lists of items, that have to be grouped, but if we process a list of items that has already been gropued, we must update that group rather than create a new one.

Comment: If I make a Member aware of their Groups, then I suppose that I could take each Member, select Groups and then recursively intersect each List<Group> on to the next, if no group was common, create it, otherwise, verify that the number of members in the group is the same as the number of members being tested (to prevent larger groups from matching subsets of members which should be treated as a different group).

I will have to test this against the hash-hack to see what performs better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a hash, as I stated in my comment way back, was the only approach I could find leading me to believe that it's not possible to query *by* a collection.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `Set.removeAll()` or `Set.retainAll()` with your two sets.

Comment: Thanks but I mean from within the JPA query itself. I have updated my quesiton to hopefully be more clear. Sorry for the confusion.